# Existence of a mass-volume astronomical chart?

Tags: mass

I've been wanting to make a mass-volume (or mass-radius) chart for astronomical objects ranging from asteroids to supermassive black holes on a log-log scale. A sort of 'Hertzsprung-Russel' type diagram but with mass and volume as the axes.

I wanted to check first to see if anyone else has done this before. Google doesn't seem to turn up anything of the sort, and so I'm wondering if anybody in the esteemed audience of Astronomy.SE would know of the existence of such a diagram.

Comment: This might be one of those "quicker to make than to search for" situations. :-)

Comment: I thought this would help but it's not for astronomy: [Collection of space exploration related infographics](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/472/12102)

Comment: What about a diameter/density chart? Or a surface-area/moment-of-inertia chart? The advantages of DIY are endless! ;-)

Comment: log mass versus log radius would do.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/9608168

But you can do literature search about the topic using NASA ADS for example, or astro-ph arxiv. They are pretty comprehensive databases of papers from astronomy/astrophysics field. If you dont find anything there you are pretty sure that no one did it. If you do find some results there (and I know for a fact that mass-size diagrams are explored/created for galaxies, clusters, etc) it might shed some light on your problem as well.

NASA ADS:
http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abstract_service.html

astro-ph arXiv:
https://arxiv.org/archive/astro-ph